# fix x and y axis format in log scale

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Here's the code I used to generate the figure

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate data
x = np.linspace(0.01, 9.9, 15)
y = np.linspace(0.07, 0.7, 15)


matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 20

# legend
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.frameon'] = False
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 'medium'

# ticks
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 10.0
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 5.0
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 2.0
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 2.0
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 8.0

matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 10.0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.minor.size'] = 5.0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.major.width'] = 2.0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.minor.width'] = 2.0
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 8.0


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', color='k')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(xmin=0.005, xmax=10)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(ymin=0.07, ymax=0.7)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

# x axis format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))

# y axis format
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.1f"))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.1f"))

# borders 
plt.axhline(0.07, color='k', lw=2)
plt.axhline(0.7, color='k', lw=2)
plt.axvline(0.005, color='k', lw=2)
plt.axvline(10, color='k', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I have the following questions

1- how can I fix the x-axis formatting so that the last 2 numbers should be written 1 and 10 (instead of 1.00 and 10.00)?

2- on the y-axis: I don't want all the numbers to be written, only few. How can I fix it to: 0.07, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6?

3- How can I remove the ticks from the corners?

### Edit 1 (more details for question # 3)

If you look more carefully, in the figure below inside the blue rectangle, the corner is not smooth. That's because I plotted a line using `plt.axhline` and `plt.axvline` (to make the borders thick). The ticks on the corners overplotted by these lines makes the corners not smooth. My idea was to remove the ticks on the corners to make it smooth. Unless there is a smarter way that I am not aware of.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question #1, the following format setting is what you need:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def customizedLogFormat(x,pos):
  decimalplaces = int(np.maximum(-np.log10(x),0))
  formatstring = '{{:.{:1d}f}}'.format(decimalplaces)      
  return formatstring.format(x)
```

and then

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(customizedLogFormat))
```

For your question #2, I don't really know a smart way to achieve your goal... But after some tests, I think 'set_yticks' is one possible way to do that:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
#ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))  
ax.set_yticks([0.07, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6])
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

For your question #3, you can set the ticks position by the following code:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
```

[image]

Comment: Oooops. @aloha. I think I misunderstand what you want in Q3. What do you mean 'removing the ticks from corner'? I can't image it. Show us a clear example.

Comment: I added more details to Q3. Your answer to my Q1 somehow doesn't change the output. I still get the same figure. Any idea why?

Comment: Answer to Q1 worked, I had something wrong in my code. A2 also worked. I still need to fix Q3. many thanks

Comment: @aloha I understand your question know. All you have to do is change the setting of the axis range. For example, plt.xlim(xmin=0.0055, xmax=10.0005). So that the ticks won't appear on the border of your plots. But please remember to change the position of your additional borders.

Comment: the answer to Q3 is simple: `matplotlib.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2`